# Dismiss rewarded ads programmatically after user received reward

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I want to dismiss the ad `rewardedAd` after the user has received the reward. It seems that [rewardedAds](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads) does not have the function, such as, `dismiss` or `setVisibility` like View. The call back in the documentation looks like this:

```
  var rewardedAd: RewardedAd? = null
  ....
  myButton.setOnClickListener {
  if (rewardedAd.isLoaded) {
    val adCallback = object: RewardedAdCallback() {
      ...
      override fun onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull reward: RewardItem) {
        // User earned reward and how to close the ads here?
      }
      ...
    }
    rewardedAd.show(activityContext, adCallback)
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled by the user? As in when to close the Ad. Instead of doing this programmatically? This might be good for the user because they don't have to intervene but not so good for the Ad company because their Ads are being closed programmatically. Maybe that's why Google has not implemented the functionality to close the ads?

Comment: Yeah, the advertiser doesn't want their ad to disappear before the user has a chance to click, or it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call onBackPressed() once.